# PouchDB transaction error

Tags: javascript, jquery, pouchdb

I am hoping someone has some ideas. This is causing me some real problems:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': The database connection is closing. {message: "Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': The database connection is closing.", name: "InvalidStateError", code: 11, stack: "Error: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBData…ss (http://x.example.com/jav.js:352:56)", INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1…}n.openTransactionSafely @ pouchdb-3.3.1.min.js:7e._get @ pouchdb-3.3.1.min.js:8(anonymous function) @ pouchdb-3.3.1.min.js:7(anonymous function) @ pouchdb-3.3.1.min.js:10(anonymous function) @ pouchdb-3.3.1.min.js:10(anonymous function) @ pouchdb-3.3.1.min.js:10(anonymous function) @ pouchdb-3.3.1.min.js:10(anonymous function) @ pouchdb-3.3.1.min.js:10$.ajax.success @ jav.js:352j @ jquery.js:3094k.fireWith @ jquery.js:3206x @ jquery.js:8259k.cors.a.crossDomain.send.b @ jquery.js:8600
```

That is the error I occasionally get in PouchDB. It happens when I:

1. Get all tasks
2. One-by-one, send each task to the webservice to store in a remote database
3. When the response is returned, delete that task from PouchDB
   The rationale is that only once it is confirmed by the webservice, then it will delete the task off the mobile phone (which this app is used on). But the problem is, due to this error it never deletes the first task - meaning many duplicates as the user will sync repeatedly wondering why it is not working.
4. Continue to the next task and repeat from step 2 onwards.

The error happens around step 3, on the `get` call. It seems to be happening on the very first call (ie. if there are 3 tasks, it fails trying to `get` the first).

I just want to stress - this doesn't happen all the time. Only every so often. From Googling around I can see there is not a lot of documentation about this issue, but it appears to be caused by a race condition somewhere.

I am hoping even if the problem is in PouchDB itself, perhaps there is some way I can refactor my own code such that this won't be so much of an issue.

```
        var tasks = [];
        myDatabase.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then(function(result) {
            totalTasks = result.total_rows;

            // Save the tasks
            for (var i = 0; i < totalTasks; i++) {
                tasks.push(result.rows[i].doc.task)
            }

            // If there are tasks...
            if (tasks.length > 0) {
                var syncLogic = function() {

                    // When the user clicks the sync button; send it off
                    var postData = {
                        // Use the username previously submitted
                        auth: {
                            username: username,
                        },

                        // Empty task because this is a shell - we'll overwrite that when we actually send the task
                        task: ''
                    };

                    // Link to the webservice
                    var postLink = syncHttpLink;

                    // Recursive function, because we need to send tasks one at a time
                    // That way if there's a failure, we'll never have to send the whole lot again
                    // and risk duplicate tasks.
                    var sendToWebService = function (count) {
                        postData.task = tasks[count];
                        count++;

                        var jsonStringifyPostData = JSON.stringify(postData);

                        $.ajax({
                            url: postLink,
                            cache: false,
                            type: 'POST',
                            timeout: 180000,
                            data: jsonStringifyPostData,

                            // When the data has been sent
                            complete: function () {
                                // Complete - nothing here currently
                            },

                            // When it's successful we'll get a response
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (!data.authenticates) {
                                    // Log auth error
                                    // ...
                                }

                                if (data.authenticates && data.synced) {
                                    // They logged in, the task has synced. Delete the document from the internal database.

  // THIS LINE HERE IS WHERE IT CAUSES THE ERROR:
  myDatabase.get(data.id).then(function (doc) {
                                        myDatabase.remove(doc, function(error, response) {
                                            if (error) {
                                                // Log the error
                                                console.log("Database delete error:" + error);
                                            }

                                            else {
                                                console.log("Database record deleted: " + data.id);

                                                // Send the next task
                                                if (count <= (totalTasks - 1)) {
                                                    sendToWebService(count);
                                                }

                                                else {
                                                    // Finished
                                                    exitSync();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    });
                                }
                            },

                            // If there's an error...
                            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                        });
                    };

                    // First call!
                    sendToWebService(0);
                };
            }
        });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I opened up a Github issue: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/3802. It's probably more practical to discuss over there than in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also another thing: you could simplify your code A LOT if you used `Promise.all()` instead of manually creating a task queue. You can use Promises from PouchDB via `PouchDB.utils.Promise`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, I was aware of this problem, but I thought it was only possible if you were using map/reduce queries and `destroy()`. If you're using neither one (and it seems that way), then that's a very interesting data point. Can you provide a live test case to reproduce?

Also, what browser are you using and what version of PouchDB?

**Edit**: I rewrote your code using `Promise.all` so you can see how it can save you a lot of coding! Not directly related to your question, but I like teaching people about the joy of Promises. :)

```
myDatabase.allDocs({
  include_docs: true
}).then(function(result) {
  // post all the data
  return PouchDB.utils.Promise.all(result.rows.map(function (row) {
    var postData = JSON.stringify({
      auth: { username: username },
      task: row.doc.task
    });
    return new PouchDB.utils.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
          url: postLink,
          cache: false,
          type: 'POST',
          timeout: 180000,
          data: postData,

          success: function(data) {
            if (!data.authenticates) {
              reject(new Error('authentication error'));
            } else {
              // resolve the promise with the doc, so it will appear in the next step
              resolve(row.doc);
            }
          },

          error: reject
      }));
    });
  });
}).then(function (docs) {
  // remove all the docs
  return PouchDB.utils.Promise.all(docs.map(function (doc) {
    return myDatabase.remove(doc);
  }));
}).catch(function (err) {
  // any errors along the way will end up in a single place
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Hi I am also having the same problem. can i share my code so that you can look into it. it's so what urgent. any help much appreciated.